# Noise at hall sensor output from motor

Tags: dc-motor, noise, encoder, hall-effect

I have motor with build in hall sensor(sc2546). I am controlling speed with 4 mosfet bridge duty cycle modulation. Frequency is about 20 kHz. Motor is powered with separate power supply and it is galvanically isolated from hall sensor power supply. Hall sensor wires are shielded and shield is grounded with hall sensor power supply ground. I want to read pulses from hall sensor but signal is completely destroyed with noise.
What I am doing wrong?
It is something wrong with motor and hall sensor?
EDIT:
When I use 100 % duty cycle the noise disappear.
[image]

This is my bridge:

[image]

Comment: Show us your ground signal pls. You may also have high shootthru pulses and too long a gnd clip with untwisted unshielded pairs

Comment: What do you mean by ground signal? How should I measure ground when it is measured respect to ground? Please explain. 